How to remove MAUI .NET Entry white space?
I've a entry in my android app. As in picture, text is clipped, and there is  a big white space around. Is it possible to made text bigger, without clipping it, reducing the white space?
 <Style TargetType="Entry">
    <Setter Property="FontAutoScalingEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Micro"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="End"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
</Style>

Entry is
<Entry Placeholder="15"   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4"     Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

I've the same iusse with all the entries in this application.
Layout is made by this grid:
   <Grid Margin="5">
       
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
       

       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

and I'm using 4 with display 1280x720 440dpi.

It works well on my site, see this effect. My environment is .NET 8 | simulator Android 13.0 API 33

Could you provide xaml code of your entry and other related layout?

@Jianwei Sun - MSFT added some layout ad details

Try to set a value to RowSpacing like this?

Well, as answer, about this situation:

How to remove MAUI .NET Entry white space?

Give a positive value to RowSpacing (negative value can cause that effect):
<Grid Margin="5" Padding="5" RowSpacing="20" ColumnSpacing="0" WidthRequest="200">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Entry Placeholder="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  />
    <Entry Placeholder="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
    <Entry Placeholder="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />
    <Entry Placeholder="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Entry Placeholder="15" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Entry Placeholder="15" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
    <Entry Placeholder="15" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" />
    <Entry Placeholder="15" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
</Grid>


Tried but I got the same result. any idea? In buttons I set padding to 0 to do that, but entry doesn't have this property
